# Fatal error: Class 'TestCase' not found in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpstorm

I create a new laravel 5 project and have this error:

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:/Users/Night/AppData/Local/Temp/ide-phpunit.php --no-configuration C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelProject
Testing started at 11:43 AM ...

Fatal error: Class 'TestCase' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelProject\tests\ExampleTest.php on line 8

Process finished with exit code 255
```

I run phpunit tests/ in the directory of my project(C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelProject) but it doesn't work.

```
PHPUnit 4.8.16 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
.
Time: 842 ms, Memory: 8.75Mb

OK (1 test, 2 assertions)
```

I'm using phpstorm 9.0 laravel 5 php 5.6

Comment: 1) How did you install PHPUnit? I guess via Composer? 2) Please show screenshots of how you configured it in PhpStorm.

Answer (score 3):

Phpstorm does not know how to autoload the classes required for the project. Set up your debug configuration to use the default phpunit.xml located at the project root.

[image]

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer

Comment: Looks like an answer to me.

Comment: This solved the problem on NetBeans 8.1 too. Thank you!

Comment: which is the default `phpunit.xml`? I have no `phpunit.xml` in project root directory

Comment: If your using Laravel it should have one but if not you can copy it from the repo https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/phpunit.xml. just be sure to switch to the correct branches for your project.